# Rails date_select class not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello I am trying to make a date_select and the class wont take effect. Thanks for all the help.

```
<%= f.date_select :created_at,
:order => [:month, :day, :year],
:prompt => {month:  'Birth Month', day: 'Birth Day', year: 'Birth Year'},
:start_year => Time.now.year,
:end_year => 1920,
:class => 'SelectDropDown' %>
```

Comment: I figured it out just wrapped it in a div with that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the form helper that I like is called [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form). When I need to add a date picker I have been using [bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails](https://github.com/TrevorS/bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails)

Setup:

File #app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({});
    return $('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
      format: 'YYYY/MM/DD'
    });
  });
});
```

Now to apply it to a form

= f.input :date_select, as: :string, input_html: { class: 'datetimepicker', value: "#{f.created_at}" }

I hope that this helps

Answer (score 0):

try to use html_options  for class:

```
<%= f.date_select :created_at,
order: [:month, :day, :year],
prompt: {month:  'Birth Month', day: 'Birth Day', year: 'Birth Year'},
start_year: Time.now.year,
end_year: 1920,
html_options: {class: "SelectDropDown"} %>
```

for more details check [data_select](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/date_select)